# How can I match a named route, *then* a dynamic route in Express.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

```
app.get('/post/create', create_post);
app.get('/post/:slug', view_post);
```

With routes like the following, I'd expect that when you visit `/post/create` that the `view_post` function *would not* run but that is not the case. It is matched because "create" can simply be considered the value for `:slug`.

Is there a way to match a route then disallow subsequent matches to that route once it's been matched?

Comment: What does your `create_post` look like? `view_post` should only be run if you are calling `next` inside `create_post`.

Comment: I just set ut a blank express app myself to test this out and I got the behaviour you are expecting. You should post more of your code if you are still having problems, because this should work the way you assumed it would.

Answer (score 0):

I found the *real* culprit of the strange errors I'm seeing. I'm still new to Express and node in general, so go easy on me!

My favicon was not prefixed with a `/` so it was searching for `/post/favicon.ico` as a route and giving me the errors I was experiencing.